# Strings including html for localisation

Tags: localization

How to localise this string (including html) ?

```
     echo "<div class='updated'><p>All options are restored successfully.</p></div>" ;
```

Is this correct?

```
     echo '<div class="updated"><p>' . __( 'All options are restored successfully.', 'mytextdomain' ) . '</p></div>';
```

And how to go about this one?

```
     <p><?php _e( 'On the <a href="' . get_admin_url() . 'import.php">Import</a> page, choose the previously created file and click the <strong>Upload file and import</strong> button.', 'mytextdomain' ); ?></p>
```

Comment: If you want to return the string, use `__()`, if you want to echo, use `_e()`. So, `_e()` is exactly the same as `echo __()`.

Comment: Had a mistake there, edited, so it's correct now?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. A simple _test_ with a real translation could have told you that. Somehow I don’t see you actual problem?

Comment: I know it works, I just wanted to confirm that it's the proper way to do it, and if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: @drtanz You asked **111(!!)** questions so far. You should _really_ know how to do an update of a question and that posting updates as comments in inappropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is correct, simply because it works. There are hundreds of ways to localize strings wich are displayed including html, all good and elegant in their own way.

I like to do this as follows:

```
printf( '<div class="updated">
        <p>%1$s</p>
    </div>',
    __( 'All options are restored successfully.', 'mytextdomain' )
);
```

You also could do this like:

```
$str = __( 'All options are restored successfully.', 'mytextdomain' );
echo "<div class='updated'><p>$str</p></div>";
```

The most important thing is to maintain readability I guess. There isn't a "correct" way to display localized strings in combination with html.

For your second one, I would use:

```
_e( sprintf( 'On the <a href="%1$s">Import</a> page, choose the previously created file and click the <strong>Upload file and import</strong> button.', get_admin_url() . 'import.php' ), 'mytextdomain' );
```

In this case, the URL doesn't have to be translated.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, how would you go about the second example I put in the updated question?

Comment: I updated my answer with my opinion on your second example. :-)